# Connect from Windows client to Ubuntu 18.04 with installed Samba not working

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, samba

I installed and configured samba in Ubuntu 18.04 with following installation guide:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-samba-on-ubuntu-18-04/

The only thing i didn't made (from the installation notes) is that i didn't configure the samba user josh. I have ONLY configured the user sadmin.

If i try to connect from my Windows 10-Laptop to Ubuntu 18.04 with the command
`net use Z: \\192.168.0.100\users /u:sadmin password` i only got the message "Systemfehler 53 aufgetreten."

If i try to execute the command `smbclient //192.168.0.100/users -U sadmin` in Ubuntu i get the message "Connection to 192.168.0.100 failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)". I made some internet research, but i didn't find where the problem of the samba configuration is.

Further notes:
- There is no firewall installed on Ubuntu at the moment

Can you help me? Thanxs in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, Samba is failing to bind to Network Interface(used for connection to other machine), generally, it's eth0. Set `[bind to interfaces only]` line in `smb.conf` to `FALSE/no`(I don't know why both versions exist) and reload Samba.

Comment: Thanks! It works now fine with the config change! I accept this answer

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept this as answer for future readers